# Django haystack narrow with OR operator between fields

Tags: filter, django-haystack, narrowing

I do a search. I narrow by field A. I narrow by field B. I get results that include burlap AND sack. What I want is to get results that include burlap OR sack.

```
sqs = sqs.narrow(fieldA='burlap')
sqs = sqs.narrow(fieldB='sack')
```

You can do some level of OR narrowing with the following:

```
sqs = sqs.narrow(fieldA=('burlap' or 'tweed' or 'plastic'))
sqs = sqs.narrow(fieldB='sack')
```

But you still end up with results with burlap AND sack. An alternative to this method is the following, but it is not ideal since it seems to be slow on large data sets:

```
sqs = sqs.filter_or(fieldA='burlap')
sqs = sqs.filter_or(fieldB='sack')
```

Where is Daniel Lindsay when you need him?

Answer (score 2):

YMMV -- the docs (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#narrow) point out that this method is not portable between backends and that the syntax depends on the backend. The example in that section even has a lucene looking "SearchQuerySet().narrow('title:smoothie')" example.

In the source it looks like haystack pretty trustingly passes whatever you have as your narrow argument to the back end. You didn't say what backend you are using, but maybe something like this would get you the fq you want in solr:

```
    sqs = sqs.narrow('fieldA:burlap OR fieldB:sack')
```

Filter_or is a different animal than narrow, at least with solr. Filter_or will add that clause to the main query, resulting in a different set of results, different scoring, etc. Narrow will create a filter query. This is instead used to filter your original results (shocking, right?) and it can be cached, which can help performance if you're going to be using that filter a lot.

D'oh, I typed all that stuff and still don't know where Daniel Lindsay is.